# How add or set a file version in .exe file using command line or PowerShell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, build

I have an file **.exe** format. I want to set version to this file in  time build project automatically from script. I can't set version to this file from Visual Studio, because I have only exe file.
How can I add a file version to a file information using command line or PowerShell without third-party programs ?

Comment: You can't. See [versioning - Powershell Set FileVersion - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53144259/powershell-set-fileversion)

Comment: There is a FREE program which may allow you to do this, "Resource Hacker", but it is a 3rd-party tool. I have never used to it set file versions however I have seen them inside the program using the said program. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, colleagues!